# Unit test AWS S3 functions with Mocha in Node

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, amazon-s3, mocha.js

How can I mock S3 calls when unit testing in Node. I want to make sure the function is unit tested without making actual calls to S3. I would like to test what happens if everything goes as expected and if there are errors. I think Sinon is the tool of choice but I'm not sure how?

My s3 file is:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.region = 'ap-southeast-2';
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const { S3_BUCKET } = process.env;
const propertyCheck = require('./utils/property-check');

module.exports.uploadS3 = (binary, folderName, fileName) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!propertyCheck.valid(binary) ||
        !propertyCheck.validString(folderName) ||
        !propertyCheck.validString(fileName)) {
        const error = '[uploadS3] Couldn\'t upload to S3 because of validation errors.';
        console.error(error);
        return reject(new Error(error));
    }
    const finalUrl = `${encodeURIComponent(folderName)}/${encodeURIComponent(fileName)}`;
    s3.putObject({
        Body: binary,
        Key: finalUrl,
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
        ContentType: 'application/pdf',
        ContentDisposition: 'inline',
        ACL: 'public-read'
    }, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return reject(new Error(`[uploadS3] ${error}`));
        }
        resolve(`https://${S3_BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com/${finalUrl}`);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Sinon is a great choice.

You could use `aws-sdk-mock` as it takes out a little bit of the work involved with setting up mocks, but will you probably find yourself using both.

**Link to `aws-sdk-mock`:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-mock)

---

As an aside, you can replace your manual Promise creation with `.promise()` that is on most of the `aws-sdk` API.

**Documentation Link:** http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#promise-property